# SqlException constraint violation

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, exception

I'm working on an asp.net app.
Is there a way, when catching a SqlException, 
to know which constraint was violated?

Comment: yep. I just want to know if the user is violating, say, a unique constraint, so the app can inform which inserted data is wrong

Answer (score 8):

SqlException has a collection of SqlError objects: [Errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.errors.aspx). The [SqlError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlerror.aspx) have properties for error [Number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlerror.number.aspx) and you can compare this with the known constraint violation error numbers (eg. 2627).

While is true that SqlException itself exposes a Number property, it is not accurate if multiple errors happen in a single batch and hence is better to inspect the Errors collection.

Answer (score 4):

```
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    if (ex.Errors.Count > 0) // Assume the interesting stuff is in the first error
    {
        switch (ex.Errors[0].Number)
        {
            case 547: // Foreign Key violation
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Your FK user-friendly description", ex);
                    break;
            // other cases
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In this particular case you can use ex.Number for simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add exception handler for the ConstraintException if I understand your question correctly

```
try
{

}
catch(ConstraintException exc)
{
//exc.Message 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you letting the exception bubble up?  If you don't catch it and turn custom errors off in the web.config i believe it will display it in your browser.  If you are catching it i would put a break point in the catch section and inspect the exception there.

Answer (score -1):

The best thing is to catch this catch exception in your C# code behind.

```
catch(SqlException ex)
{
    if (ex.Message.Contains("UniqueConstraint"))
        throw new UniqueConstraintException();

    throw;
}
```

You can create your own exception and throw that from your data layer, otherwise you can directly catch the exception as mentioned above.

```
using System; 

public class UniqueConstraintException : Exception
{
}
```

Comment: -1 for `UniqueConstraintException : Exception` (bypassing SqlException). Also because there is `ConstraintException` in .NET framework already.

Comment: @Neolisk Except ConstraintException is part of the DataTable/DataRow stuff, and since SqlException is sealed, you can't inherit from it.  Although you can inherit from DbException, and I'd recommend that.